# Android framework for Scala

Tags: android, scala, frameworks, client

So, I have server application written in Scala using playframework. Now I need to make client for Android (in Scala) which will interact with server by HTTP requests. I have not much experience in Android development. And because of it I have the question. Is there any framework for this kind of things?

Data from the server to the client transmitted in a Json format.

Comment: Intellij Idea + Scala plugin is fine enough. Of course proguard setup for Scala is required. You can find it at http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#manual/examples.html . Just extend Android Java framework. Besides you can use those enhancers: http://github.com/pocorall/scaloid and http://github.com/macroid/macroid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [Proguard for Scala](https://github.com/banshee/AndroidProguardScala) and this [documentation](http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/androiddevelopment/index.html).